# Sending files through java server by byte[]

Tags: java, sockets, http, web

I am trying to send files (html, css, and images) through Java server socket. I was able to send html and css, except for images..

```
ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
File fp = new File(file);
byte[] arrByte = new byte[4096];            
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fp);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

int count;
while((count = fis.read(arrByte)) > 0 ) {
    os.write(arrByte, 0, count);                
}
```

My client (receiver) is the web server. Below is my response header:

```
        header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n" + 
                "Connection: close \n" + 
                "Date: " + new Date().toString() + " \n" +
                "Content-Type: image/jpg \n" + 
                "Content-Length: " + fp.length() + " \n" + 
                "\r\n";
```

I can't seem to find which part I am lacking... How do I get the images load to the server?

Comment: What fails when sending images? Do you get an error or is the image "broken" on the receiving side?
How do you receive and save the bytes?

Comment: Image is broken.. I am using browser as the reciever -- basically, i proceed to 127.0.0.1:8888/index.html 
HTML and CSS appear correctly in the browser, but images are "broken".

Comment: There is no code here that sends the response header you posted. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you're receiving HTTP requests, you have to send HTTP responses, not just the content of the image file. You have to send the appropriate HTTP headers and *then* the content.

NB The line terminator in HTTP is specified as `\r\n`, not `\n`, and, what is worse, you are using a mixture of both.

Answer (score -1):

Try with ImageIO API.

- Read the image bytes via ImageIO
- Use ImageIO to transform and write it to intermittent ByteArrayOutputStream
- Use ImageIO to write from intermittent ByteArrayOutputStream to the socket

  ```
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
  BufferedImage imageBytes = ImageIO.read(in);
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
  ImageIO.write(imageBytes, "png", baos );
  byte[] outBytes = baos.toByteArray();
  os.write(outBytes, 0, out.length);
  ```

Comment: Try it why? What's wrong with just copying the actual bytes? It's a lot more time- and space-efficient, for a start. Posting an alternative does not constitute identifying a problem in the OP's code.

Answer (score -1):

It seem to me that you are not closing the streams, therefore not all bytes are necessarily written to the client. Use a `try-with-resources` construction to ensure the `OutputStream` is getting closed. If you have Java 7 or above you can use the `Files.copy` to have the stream copied.

```
 Path path = Paths.get(file);
 try (OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream()) {
     Files.copy(path, os);
 )
```

Comment: TCP writes data to the client whether you close the socket or not.